# Automata Homework Questions

Tags: automata, formal-languages

Can anyone check these to see if I did them correctly. Thanks
* Also I'm not sure on how to do number 8 if anyone can help me out that should be awesome.

https://s.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/1502abb1407b4069b0664f88d93bddd0_A.jpeg?a=answers&mr=0&x=1443655904&s=7662a2708cc0621f20fa6594dd5ea97a

Comment: This is not your free homework-checking service.

Comment: Please copy the content into the question body. Nobody wants to go to your link.